# Pulling strings...not legs?

Tags: three-dimensional, topology

What happens to the two strings - of the logo of **G20 Summit**  [image](currently happening in Germany)-if pulled either side (in opposite directions, away from the center) at the same time ?

Your options are:

**(a)** They separate out as two different strings
**(b)** They get tied to each other- as a knot
**(c)** They just hold each other by a single strand
**(d)** None of the above

Also explain *why /how*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the ropes are flexible and have a low coefficient of friction, it depends on which 'sides' you pull. Labeling the 4 ends A, B, C, D (and the mid-points AC and BD, then, if you pull two ends (or an end and a middle):

> Pulling A and B or A and D or A and BD or C and B or C and D or C and BD or B and AC or D and AC, or AB and CD the ropes will separate into two length. Whereas pulling A and C or B and D, one rope will straighten and the other will end up hanging in a twisted loop around it (see figure).

If you pull three ends and/or middles:

> Pulling on three points on one rope (for example A C and AC) won't undo the 'knot', but pulling on any two points on one rope and a third point on the other rope will separate them into two lengths.

...and if you pull all four ends

> Pulling on all four ends will tighten the knot.

Picture showing pulling on ends A and C

> [image]

If there is friction in the ropes, or if the hidden ends are not open, then all bets are off.

Comment: Wow ! Good one !! @Penguino, your answer is much clearer and to the point (I mean in terms of the options I have provided for this puzzle) are relevant straight to the question. I should definitely accept this as the most comprehensive and apt answer for my question than the previous ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is actually a puzzle more than a general knowledge question but:

> The G20 Summit Logo is actually a Reef Knot, so it you pull the 'ends' tight it is the knot **(b)**, if you pull the 'loops' from the centre if would come loose and providing the strings are cut as shown in the logo, they would separate out as two strings **(a)**.

The knot looks like this:

> [image]

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree. A picture of a reef knot and asking what happens when you pull the ends isn't really a puzzle...

Comment: Good information @BreakingMyself. Informative. I am an amateur in stackexchange. So kindly bear with me.

Comment: Well Chris, I am getting to understand the kind of jargon / type of puzzles being asked. So please cooperate :-).

Comment: @ChandrasekharK I'd recommend reading through a few posts and checking the tag descriptions here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags for different puzzles and topics shared on the site. I'm relatively new myself so don't worry about it :)